# Are these gigantic stones in Russia from a technologically advanced ancient civilization?

Tags: history

According to the [Atlantean Gardens blog](http://atlanteangardens.blogspot.com/2014/04/massive-megalithic-stone-ruins.html?spref=fb) humans worked 3000 ton stones were found in Russia.

[image: Example of Stones]

[The Rundown Live has more photos.](http://therundownlive.com/largest-blocks-stone-ever-discovered-megalithic-ruins-russia/)

[Dr Valery Uvarov](http://wands-of-horus.com/en/) thinks they are man-made. He is "Head of the Department of Palaeoscience, Palaeotechnology, and UFO Research of the National Security Academy of Russia".

Is this site from an ancient advanced civilization?

Comment: Just to be clear, in Russia there is Russian Academy of Sciences, which is an official and credible organization. There are also a few dozen of institutions which call themselves "academy", but don't have any affiliation with The Academy. They give each other medals, prizes, degrees, etc., but most of them are merely labels to add (unjustified) credibility and bloat the ego of their members. The most notorious is Russian Academy of Natural Sciences, which can boast of having prophets, remote healers, alien contactees etc as its members.

Comment: How do you define "advanced civilization"? Any civilization is advanced relative to anything less advanced.

Answer (score 12):

This is very interesting. I am going to elaborate on Valery Uvarov first.

Let's have a look at Dr Valery Uvarov. It seems very hard to get a biography of the guy, the only [information](http://www.bibliotecapleyades.net/esp_autor_uvarov_a.htm) I can find is:

> Dr Valery Mikhailovich Uvarov is the head of the Department of UFO Research, Palaeosciences and Palaeotechnology of the National Security Academy of Russia, and has devoted more than 14 years to ufology as well as to the study of the legacy of ancient civilizations.
>
> He is the author of numerous papers on palaeotechnology and palaeoscience, as well as ufology and esoterica, published in the Russian and foreign press.

So if he really is a specialist in Palaeoscience, that would make him the right person to assess this kind of phenomenon. I did a [search](http://scholar.google.ch/scholar?start=0&q=author:Valery%20author:Uvarov&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) for papers authored by him in English, however the only documents that match him are his books on ufology. This means that he hasn't published any papers in a reputable, international journal on Geology or Palaeoscience which makes me rather sceptical about his authority in the field.

The National Security Academy of Russia where he apparently works, is only ever mentioned in [connection with him](https://www.google.ch/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=National%20Security%20Academy%20St.%20Petersburg&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=gbpWU9i1IePW8geLhIHgCw). So that means either he is the only member of that academy that ever translates the name into English or it's a made-up institute.

That is all the information that I can find about him. But given that he does not seem to publish in scientific journals (or at least international ones), never gives information on his exact education background and works at a fictitious academy, I doubt he is what you would call a credible scientist.

Now on the matter itself, are those stones man-made?.

The story about those structures seems to be pretty new, so I couldn't find much reliable information on how they could have been formed.

What makes you say those structures are not natural formations? If you look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXeuTK2fhwI) of the site, it looks a lot less like a man-made structure.

There are plenty of similar structures that a layman would identify as man-made but that are actually natural. Examples are the [Giant's Causeway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant%27s_Causeway) in Northern Ireland or structures called [tors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28rock_formation%29), that look like piled up blocks.

**TL;DR**

Valery Uvarov doesn't have a scientific track record and is not a credible scientist. As of now, nothing indicates that those structures are man-made.

Comment: Did you include journals in Russian?

Comment: No, I didn't, because I don't speak Russian. Would be nice if somebody could do that, it would complete the picture.

Comment: @dart True, but you might want to update your answer to indicate you limited your search to English publications. The lack of peer reviewed publications is a potential red flag, but by no means proof that someone isn't an authority in their field.

Comment: I've made a search in Russian. 1. The academy's site is on a free hosting: http://anb-rf.narod.ru. No mention of any members but Uvarov in Russian as well. There seems to be a different one with the same name http://www.academnb.ru. 2. Here is Uvarov's site: http://wands-of-horus.com which is full of stuff like healing by trees, life energy, pyramids as magnetic coils etc. 3. No mention of his alleged doctorate degree on Russian version of the sites. 4. No papers in Russian apart from two books about pyramids.

Comment: Found one paper in google scholar which is titled "Holy Russia: cosmic beginnings", not in refereed journal.

Comment: @sashkello thanks, that seems to be consistent with my conclusion then

Comment: @rob yes, you are of course right, but I think together with all the other indices this makes for a pretty good case against him